# Why is my java test script for selenium not printing out a simple confirmation string?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

I am trying to finish a test script written in `Java`. Everything works great and I am trying to print out a confirmation if all previous steps runs which says that account creation was successful.

To do this, I have put the element in a string and then print out the element using the `System.out.println` command. But for some reason , all I am getting is the following

CONFIRMATION:
That's it. It's supposed to show the string text which reads " Customer information added successfully" . I been trying for the past 2 hours to get it to print it. Can someone please help ?

Here's my code that's causing the problem.

```
String conf = driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_lblTransactionResult")).getText();
    System.out.println("CONFIRMATION: " + conf);
```

*I have checked and rechecked the element id and it is the correct element id.*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAmxH.jpg  ( Confirmation page )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt4t2.jpg  ( Eclipse output )

Comment: Do you get a valid return from driver.findElement(By.id(...))?

Comment: How do you mean? I am trying to get a valid return by printing out the string named "conf". Is that what you meant? Sorry.

Comment: WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_lblTransactionResult")); Check if a WebElement is returned

Comment: I tried to run it, but it's giving me a red x mark next to the line.Upon hovering on WebElement, it's saying "

Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.
"

Comment: what is the error message return?

Comment: When I click on the red x mark next to the WebElement line, it says "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"

Comment: There is a weird token between the last two parenthesis. Remove that.

Comment: How do I remove that? I am fairly new to Selenium. sorry.

Comment: The actual line I provided has an invalid token in it somehow. Retype the sentence or remove the token.

Comment: I just retyped the sentence and the x mark went away. But it's still not printing anything for the webelement "we". I did a sys out and it appears that it's skipping the line.  System.out.println("test" + we);

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. I saved my file as UTF-8 and now it's printing this following :- test[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (0acb075a-3a0b-443e-940e-80a62a3a575a)] -> id: MainContent_lblTransactionResult]

Comment: Is your problem resolved changing to UTF-8?

Comment: Thanks Zachary for all your help!    
I figured it out. For some weird reason, my computer was executing the lines super fast . So fast for it to catch up. So I added a new line that forced it to wait until and only until it actually sees the element - WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.‌​id("ID"))); Now it works!

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Hi Jeff, the reason why I screenshot my code is because of the character limit . Please don't negative vote my post unnecessarily next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String conf = driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_lblTransactionResult")).innerHTML;
```

What you are trying to pull out of the element is in the innerHTML

Comment: I am trying to get the text message. That's why the code has getText(); in the end. It's just a confirmation message. So my last line is  System.out.println("CONFIRMATION: " + conf);
But the conf string is not getting picked up.

Comment: Here it is :-    <span id="MainContent_lblTransactionResult" class="heading-title">Customer information added successfully</span>

Comment: I assume you are reading the page after it is updated.   Do you add the span to the page or is the span empty and you add the confirmation.

Comment: I figured it out. For some weird reason, my computer was executing the lines super fast . So fast for it to catch up. So I added a new line that forced it to wait until and only until it actually sees the element - WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ID")));  Now it works!

Comment: So still curious.  Did you add the span or was it pulling the blank prior to the update

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand . Maybe it's because I am new to selenium. But I don't add the span anywhere. The span is in the html code itself. It's just a  html tag. Did I answer it correctly? Is this what you were hoping for? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: When the page first appears, before the user hits submit, is the span element on the web page and the inner.html is blank

Comment: Before the user hits submit , the page has this - <span id="MainContent_lblTransactionResult" class="heading-title"></span>.  After the user hits submit, the page shows <span id="MainContent_lblTransactionResult" class="heading-title">Customer information added successfully</span> . Is this a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use some delay like `Webdriver wait.until` or `Thread sleep` after hitting the submit. 
Try to get text using JavascriptExecutor like below:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String conf = jse.executeScript("$('#MainContent_lblTransactionResult').text();", "");

System.out.println("CONFIRMATION: " + conf);
```

You can also try using `.html()` instead of `.text()`

```
String conf = jse.executeScript("$('#MainContent_lblTransactionResult').html();", "");
```

Hopefully it resolves your issue.